# AndroidFoodFight footer links

Tags: bug, status-completed

Some links to other Stack sites in the footer of http://androidfoodfight.com/ are missing hyperlinks.

*See the links that are not underlined, are actually not hyperlinked:*

[image: Screenshot of AndroidFoodFight footer]

**EDIT:**

I can see what is causing the issue! Seems like a rare typo from the awesome Stack folks:

```
<div id="footer-sites">
    <span style="color:#FE7A15;font-size:140%">■</span>&nbsp;
    <a ref="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow.com</a>&nbsp; 
</div>
```

the `a` tag has attribute `ref` defined instead of `href`

Comment: Nope, still not fixed. @GAThrawn if you see all the links as clickable, do you mind posting a screenshot as an answer? coz mine still stands as the original screenshot!

Comment: Actually sorry you're right, I'd misread and through tyou were talking about the main AE site with the Foodfight theme added to it. androidfoodfight.com is showing how you said with broken hyperlinks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yup, not sure how I screwed up those `href` attributes. It's fixed now, thanks.